# Is it possible to use a Switch Case to set a different output?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I've figured out how to do this. I've passed the location name as a 3rd argument from the show_data_inline_location back on location.php back to the function by including the location name as follows:

```
show_data_inline_city($data['Cars_In_Location'], 'car', $data['Name']);
```

Then in the function itself I have done added the following argument:

```
function show_data_inline_location($data, $type, $location_name)
```

And added this to create a URL friendly string:

```
$loc_name = strtolower(str_ireplace(" ","-", $location_name));
```

Then echoing this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$link_url.$name.'-in-'.$loc_name.'"><div class="overlay">'.PHP_EOL;
```

This way I don't need to seperate the case in the switch, only need to use this for the difference between 'car' and 'location':

```
if ($type == 'car') { echo 'this'; }
if ($type == 'location') { 'that'; }
```

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: what s your question ? you want to know if it works ?

Comment: Hello, my question is to know if it's possible to do something like I've asked. I know that $loc_name = case 'location': $name; won't work but I'd like to find a solution that does in terms of using the switch case to output a different variation for the echo.

Comment: have you tried your code ?

Comment: Yes, I get a return in error_log of:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'case' (T_CASE) in .....

Comment: so you have your response, it doesn't work, and to help you it would be better to put the error ...

Comment: Thanks, so is there anything I can do to make it work... this is my question.

Comment: where do you use your `show_data_inline` ?

Comment: I show it on another php page, it is called by the page location.php as the function:

show_data_inline($data['Cars_In_Location'], 'car');

Comment: Maybe I'm lacking coffee or maybe your question isn't written very well (or both), but I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do or what your problem is. Maybe a [mcve] would help.

Comment: Hi domdom, thanks for the reply. I have edited the code to show what I output as show_data_inline on location page. If on the location page I use case 'car' then it outputs a line of available cars as a banner. If I use case 'location' then it outputs a line of related locations as a banner.

What I am trying to do is use the $name from the 'location' case so that I can use it in the 'car' case as $loc_name so that I can create a longer url with both car name and location name in it to direct to specific pages.

I really don't know how to explain it otherwise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your `$data` array there is one car and one location then you can do the following to save the variables and use them later:

```
$loc_name = '';
$car_name = '';
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
          if ( is_special_car($value['name']) ) 
             continue;

    switch ($type) {
        case 'car':
            $car_name = $name;
            break;
        case 'location':
            $loc_name = $name;
             break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if($loc_name && $car_name){
         //You have a car and loc name now
    }
}
```

If your `$data` array is different you will have to modify the code of course, maybe resetting the `$loc_name` and `$car_name` when you've done whatever you needed to after getting them.

Comment: Hi Teun, thanks for the answer. What I am trying to do is to use the case 'location' $name in the case 'car' as $loc_name. 

Say for example: 
$link_url.$name = http://url.com/audi-a8
$link_url.$name.$loc_name = http://url.com/audi-a8-in-cannes

Comment: Hi Teun, and thank you for that. I have tried what you said but there is not both $car_name and $loc_name so the code will not echo. So this means that it's not getting one or the other, but not sure which as there is nothing in the error log. $data in this case simply returns the cars that are available in that location.

Comment: can you show the `$data` array you're using as example?

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working! I will post answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to do this. I've passed the location name as a 3rd argument from the show_data_inline_location back on location.php back to the function by including the location name as follows:

```
show_data_inline_city($data['Cars_In_Location'], 'car', $data['Name']);
```

Then in the function itself I have done added the following argument:

```
function show_data_inline_location($data, $type, $location_name)
```

And added this to create a URL friendly string:

```
$loc_name = strtolower(str_ireplace(" ","-", $location_name));
```

Then echoing this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$link_url.$name.'-in-'.$loc_name.'"><div class="overlay">'.PHP_EOL;
```

This way I don't need to seperate the case in the switch, only need to use this for the difference between 'car' and 'location':

```
if ($type == 'car') { echo 'this'; }
if ($type == 'location') { 'that'; }
```

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Sorry @CarySwoveland! I had not realised I'd deleted that question... I think I did it while my screen was asleep and I was clicking to awaken :O Thanks for your help if you did have an answer

Comment: I meant to say "It was a good question." :-). Sorry. I posted an answer and deleted my comment above, and after you've seen this I'll delete this comment.